# Trying to update the inputted data in my Chart.JS graph without having to reset the whole page

Tags: javascript, html, async-await, chart.js

Sorry if this is worded poorly. I have a basic website I'm working on that fetches stock data and feeds it into Chart.js. Right now I need to use the "Reset" button before submitting another stock input. I would like to make my submit button also be able to override the current graph with the new stock I input. All of my attempts and research have failed, any help would be greatly appreciated. [image]

```
"use strict";
///////////////////////////////
let input = document.getElementById("input");
const btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
const toUSD = function (number) {
  return `$${number.toLocaleString()}`;
};
const tickerSelect = document.querySelector(".stock-ticker");
const cashFlowSelect = document.querySelector(".cash-flow");
const stockData = async function (stockTicker) {
  try {
    let cashFlowArr = [];
    let stockCompArr = [];

    //////////////////////
    //Fetch stock data
    const resStock = await fetch(
      `https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/cash-flow-statement/${stockTicker}?apikey=227839811b8142d28d844e99db7d19c0&limit=120`
    );
    const dataStock = await resStock.json();

    ///////////////////////////////
    //Push data into empty arrays
    for (let i = 4; i > -1; i--) {
      cashFlowArr.push(dataStock[i].freeCashFlow);
    }
    for (let i = 4; i > -1; i--) {
      stockCompArr.push(dataStock[i].stockBasedCompensation);
    }

    //////////////////////////////
    //Chart Settings
    new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        labels: [2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: cashFlowArr,
            label: "Free Cash Flow",
            borderColor: "#3cba9f",
            fill: false,
          },
          {
            data: stockCompArr,
            label: "Stock Based Compensation",
            borderColor: "#e43202",
            fill: false,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "FCF vs SBC",
        },
      },
    });
  } catch {
    console.log("error");
  }
};

//////////////////////////
//Invoke/Event Listeners
const resetPage = function () {
  location.reload();
};
btn1.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  stockData(input.value);
});
btn2.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  resetPage();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add Data and Update Data**

1. I had created one function that can used for both create and update the chart data, Use this approach to update your chart data dynamically.
2. Also You can
   add your own fetch logic inside here

Just ignore the cross orgin script error

```js
document.getElementById('add').onclick = function(){
  const data = [{ 
        data: [86,114,106,106,107,111,133,221,783,2478],
        label: "Africa",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [282,350,411,502,635,809,947,1402,3700,5267],
        label: "Asia",
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        fill: false
      }
    ];
    CreateChart(data);
};
document.getElementById('update').onclick = function(){
  const newdata = 
    [
  { 
        data: [168,170,178,190,203,276,408,547,675,734],
        label: "Europe",
        borderColor: "#3cba9f",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [40,20,10,16,24,38,74,167,508,784],
        label: "Latin America",
        borderColor: "#e8c3b9",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [6,3,2,2,7,26,82,172,312,433],
        label: "North America",
        borderColor: "#c45850",
        fill: false
      }
  ];// array of new Data
  CreateChart(newdata);
};

let chart;

function CreateChart(data){
  if(!chart){
  chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [1500,1600,1700,1750,1800,1850,1900,1950,1999,2050],
    datasets: data
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'World population per region (in millions)'
    }
  }
});
}else{
  
  chart.data.datasets = data

  chart.update();
}

}
```

```css
main{
  height:500px;
}
.result{
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>


<main>
<div>
  <button id='add'>Add Data </button>
  <button id='update'>Update Data </button>
</div>


<div class='result'>
  <canvas id="line-chart" width="100" height="50"></canvas>
</div>

</main>
```